# Which one is correct? "I have work experience in " or "I had work experience in"?

Tags: phrases, tenses, sentence

Which one is correct?

> I have previous work experience in IBM in PHP domain during the period 2009-2010.

OR

> I had previous work experience in IBM in PHP domain during the period 2009-2010.

Comment: Both "have" and "had" are correct. They just mean different things. Since you don't tell us which thing you mean, we can't tell you which one to use. More to the point, though, there are other issues with the sentences that do make them ungrammatical. Both of them. And we do not do proofreading here, sorry. So you are asking us to pick between two equally grammatical options, and at the same time you are asking us to pick between two equally ungrammatical ones. You can drop by in our chat to have it all sorted out for you, but here on the main site this is a non-starter.

Answer (score 3):

In the context you have given the appropriate phrase is *I have work experience*...

*Had* (being the past tense) implies that you somehow used to have work experience in x, but no longer do- which, logically makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the first sentence is correct "*I have previous work experience in IBM in PHP domain during the period 2009-2010.*".
Because that is the work experience we get in the past and now we stopped work there. And now, we have experience enough for these fields . So we use have for this sentence.